# Tkinter Error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'str'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to get the user to browse for the directory location for the file to get the excel data from.
So far the broswe feature works and displays as a lable, but trying to return the label to the function of any of the button options, such as texas(), is not working.
The following error I get from the shell is:

> "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'str'"

So how do I convert the label value to string and make it work?

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *

import tkFileDialog

import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as Tk
else:
    import tkinter as Tk

import os
import tkMessageBox
root = Tk.Tk()
root.title("Excel Map Conversion")
root.geometry("450x400")# width x height

def browse_gainInfo():
    currentDir = os.getcwd()
    fname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir=currentDir, title="Please Select the Folder for Map Data Input")
    pathlabel.config(text=fname)

filepath = StringVar()

def texas():
    os.startfile(browseLink + '/Texas/Texas_conversion.py')

def state():
    os.startfile(filepath.get() + '\State\StateConv.py')

def college():

    os.startfile(filepath.get() + '\College\CollegeConv.py')

def underGrad():
    os.startfile(filepath.get() + '\Undergraduate\undergrad_conversion.py')

def grad():
    os.startfile(filepath.get()+ '\Graduate\graduate_conversion.py')

browseLabel = Label(root, text="Browse for source of Map Data").pack()
browse1 = Tk.Button(root, text='Browse', width =6, command = browse_gainInfo)
browse1.pack()
pathlabel= Label(root)
pathlabel.pack()

browseLink = StringVar(pathlabel)

label = Label(root, text="\nEnter in the filepath for the map files: \n").pack()
link = Entry(root, textvariable = filepath).pack()


label2 = Label(root, text ="\n\tPlease select from the following options:\n").pack()

button1 = Button(root, text = "College", command = college).pack()

button2 = Button(root, text= "State", command = state).pack()

button3 = Button(root, text="Texas", command = texas).pack()

button4 = Button(root, text ="Undergraduate", command = underGrad).pack()

button5 = Button(root, text ="Graduate", command = grad).pack()



#kick off the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you read the documentation for `StringVar`? Getting the value is documented.

Comment: You do the same thing for `browselink` that you did for `filepath`.

Comment: Slightly, I have read the portion detailing set function and all, but I have tried using a set function on the value and doesn't work

Comment: so set browselink to browselink=StringVar() if I understand you correctly?
Also it is that way currently, because I was testing various ways to get it to work

Comment: always put in question FULL error message (Tracebakc) - there are other usefull information - ie. which line makes problem.

Comment: to make code more readable put all functions before `root = Tk.Tk()`. You don't have to create `filepath = StringVar()` before functions - you can do it after fucntions.

Comment: if you will run code in Python 3 then you will get error on `from Tkinter import *`. And Python 3 doesn't have `tkFileDialog`, `tkMessageBox` but `tkinter.filedialog`, `tkinter.messagebox`

Comment: common mistake: `var = Widget(...).pack()` assigns `None` to `var` because `pack()/grid()/place()` returns `None`. If you need `var` then you have to do in two steps: `var = Widget(...)` and `var.pack()`. If you don't need `var` then you can do only `Widget(...).pack()`

Answer (score 0):

From the tkinterbook:

> Note that the StringVar() constructor takes an optional widget
>   argument, but no value argument; to set the value, call the set
>   method:
>
> ```
> var = StringVar()
> var.set("hello")
> ```
>
> The constructor argument is only relevant if you’re running Tkinter
>   with multiple Tk instances (which you shouldn’t do, unless you really
>   know what you’re doing).

It's probably unnecessary for what you're doing. I'm not 100% what it is you're trying to do either... but it seems like you're trying to create a `textvariable` in a roundabout way.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to get the directory path that i stated through the variable / label "pathlabel", and get that path translated as a string value so I can use it within the texas() function

Comment: Oh, try changing 'browseLink' to 'browseLink.get()' in texas(). Also, back slashes and forward slashes are going to need some work.

Comment: It returns a blank value, so it just searches for the string value for the file location ('Texas/Texas_conversion.py')
So essentially, browseLink.get() returns a blank value

Comment: @DylanF `browseLink.get()` returns blank value because you don't use it with any `Entry` and you don't use `browseLink.set("some text")`. What value do you expect ?

Comment: @furas I was basically following what Jeesubmunu said
What is your solution to this problem, to where I can get the correct text variable to use in the program?

Comment: you can't get correct text because you never use `browseLink`  to set any text inside `browseLink` - so it will be alwasy empty. You only create variable `browseLink = StringVar(pathlabel)` (but this doesn't set its value) and later you doesn't use `browseLink` so it doesn't change. It is empty all the time. I don't know what text do you expect.

Comment: If you what to set value in `browserLink` at start then you need `value=` in `browseLink = StringVar(value="some text")`. And later you can change text using `browserLink.set("new text")`, or you can assign to `Entry` to get its text - `Entry(  , textvariable=browserLink)` - but you doesn't use any of this method.

Comment: @furas I want the directory path that is labeled in pathlabel (as text)

Comment: `pathlabel` is `Label` widget - to get text from this label and set in `browserLink` you have to do manually `browserLink.set(pathlabel['text'])`. If you need this automatically then you have to use `textvariables` in `Label( ..., textvariable=browserLink)` and then in `browse_gainInfo()` only use `browserLink.set(fname)` instead of `pathlabel.config(text=fname)` - and it will set `fname` as text in `browserLink` and automatically it will change text in `pathlabel` too.

Comment: @furas That worked!
Setting it to Label(root, textvariable=browseLink) and within browse_gainInfo() to substitute with brosweLink.set(fname)
all worked and has yielded the desired results. Thank you so much!!